# How to query possible values in two tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am setting up a new query in ms access for unique values in two tables. Both table have a unique field i.e id.

Currently using join query but query is displaying records in million but my requirement is that only all records from both tables will be extracted.

```
SELECT aa.eng, aa.id, bb.arb, bb.url, bb.id
FROM Arabic AS aa INNER JOIN English AS bb ON (aa.id = bb.id)
```

;

I expect result should be visible as following i.e if english id don't have value then it will visible as blank value.

```
eng_id  arb_id
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
581026  581026
        581026
        581026
        581026
```

Sample data is given below

[image: sample_data]

Arabic table sample data

English table sample data
Updated table data
[image]

[image]

[image]

New output after id1 matching
[image]

Comment: Now sample data is available

Comment: You state that both tables have a unique ID, however, in your sample data your `id` field contains the same value for every row...

Comment: yes,actully main issue is that,id is appearing multiple time for specific detail

Answer (score 3):

You need to use left join instead of inner join

```
SELECT aa.eng, aa.id, bb.arb, bb.url, bb.id
FROM Arabic AS aa left JOIN English AS bb ON (aa.id = bb.id)
```

Comment: still same results i.e result in billions

Comment: it should work, you can add your sample data in your question @tahirmehmood

Comment: I have data in tables,how to share data,Please guide

Comment: @tahirmehmood, you need to share some sample data of your tables as like you provided your expected result

Comment: Please check now sample data is visible

Comment: you've to give sample data for 2 two table for Arabic  and English tables

Comment: sample output and input both available now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186767/discussion-between-tahir-mehmood-and-fa06).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `id` field is not unique, but rather contains the same value for every row, the result will be a **cartesian product** of the two tables, i.e. for every row in the Arabic table, all rows with a matching `id` value in the English table will be returned, with the total number of rows returned equal to the product of the number of rows in each table.

Using `select distinct` or adding a `group by` clause when selecting only the `id` fields will remove all duplicate `id` combinations, which, for your sample data will yield only one record:

```sql
select distinct aa.id, bb.id
from Arabic as aa left join English as bb on (aa.id = bb.id)
```

```sql
select aa.id, bb.id
from Arabic as aa left join English as bb on (aa.id = bb.id)
group by aa.id, bb.id
```

Result:

```
aa.id   bb.id
581026  581026
```

With a unique ID (`id1`) referencing each item, you can simply use a `LEFT JOIN` on the `id1` field, e.g.:

```sql
select aa.eng, aa.id, bb.arb, bb.url, bb.id
from Arabic aa left join English bb on (aa.id1 = bb.id1)
```

Comment: But require data in already mentioned format i.e if one table have more values with respect to specific id then other must have same rows but without any value

Comment: @tahirmehmood I don't understand the required output: since the `id` values are identical for every row, what determines how the `eng`, `url`, `arb` fields should be paired? Could you please edit your question to elaborate on the required result?

Comment: along with above id field,i have another field with name id1 which is primary key in both tables,I update table detail above,Please check

Comment: thanks,after id1 matching records are visible but again id values are not matching,what i require that if arabic have more records w.r.t to id then one English side values should be blank with id value so that both sides have same records count w.r.t to id value